# Marginal distribution question

Tags: statistics

My teacher asked us to determine the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$. I keep getting confused because of the relation between $x$ and $y$ when trying to figure out limits of integration.

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1, &0 \leq x \leq2,0\leq y \leq1, 2y\leq x\\0, &\text{ elsewhere }\end{cases}$$

$f_X(x)=\int_0^1 \ dy =1$

Similarly:

$f_Y(y)=\int_0^2 \ dx = 2$

But this seems wrong... can $f_Y(y)$ take on the value 2?

What am I doing wrong?

Any help or hints would be very appreciated!

Comment: The marginal probability distribution for $X$ is the result of integrating $f(x,y)$ over the variable $y$. The result should be a function of $x$, in your working you have ended up with a constant.
A similar comment applies to $f_{Y}(y)$ which should be a function of $y$

Answer (score 0):

The valid range for $y$ is 0 to 1 so

$$
f_{X}(x) = 
\int_{0}^{1}
f(x,y)
dy
$$

The question says, for a given $x$ value, $f(x,y)=1$ for $0\le y \le x/2$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ for $x/2 \le y \le 1$. This means that

$$
f_{X}(x) = 
\int_{0}^{0.5x}
1
\;
dy
+
\int_{0.5x}^{1}
0
\;
dy
=
0.5x
$$

$f_Y(y)$ can be found similarly.